# jQuery flowplayer tooltip: two tooltips on a single element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, flowplayer

I am using jQuery tooltip included in [flowplayer jQuery tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html). I have a requirement where I want to attach two tooltips on a single element. One when I click on the element, another when I receive response from an ajax request. Here's what I'm trying...

HTML Code is:

```
<div id="myelement"></div>

<div id="#tooltip1">This will delete your data.</div>
<div id="#tooltip2">Your data has been deleted.</div>
```

JS Code to add the tooltip and make request is:

```
$('#myelement').tooltip({
    events: {
        def: 'click, mouseleave'
    },
    tip: '#tooltip1'
});
$('#myelement').tooltip({
    events: {
        def: 'customOpenEvent, mouseleave'
    },
    tip: '#tooltip1'
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'abc.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        item:'new'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.success == 'yes') {
            // Display the new tooltip here
            $('#myelement').trigger('customOpenEvent');
        }
    }
});
```

What am I missing here? Is it even possible to assign two tooltips to a single element?

Comment: Do you need two tooltips or could you get away with changing the content of `<div id="tooltip">` as conditions change?

Comment: hmmmm. That can be an option I guess. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You could also try given them different positions so they don't fight each other for space.